# Does FORMAT provide a counter for lists iteration

Tags: common-lisp

I often want to output lists and also print their position in the list e.g.

`'(a b c)` would become `"1:A 2:B 3:C"`

As `FORMAT` already supports iterating over a given list, I was wondering whether it also provides some sort of counting directive?

E.g. the `FORMAT` string could look like this: `"~{~@C:~a~}"` whereas `~@C` would be the counter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a boring answer, here you go:

```
(format T "~:{~a:~a ~}" (loop for i from 0 for e in '(x y z) collect (list i e)))
```

And now for a more interesting one! Similarly to @Renzo's answer, this uses the Tilde directive to achieve its work.

```
(defvar *count* 0)
(defvar *printer* "~a")

(defun iterate-counting (stream arg c at)
  (declare (ignore c))
  (let ((*count* (if at -1 0)))
    (destructuring-bind (*printer* delimiter &rest args) arg
      (format stream (format NIL "~~{~~/iterate-piece/~~^~a~~}" delimiter) args))))

(defun iterate-piece (stream arg &rest dc)
  (declare (ignore dc))
  (incf *count*)
  (format stream *printer* *count* arg))
```

This uses two special variables to make it both thread-safe and to allow nesting. I won't say that it's handy to use though. The first item of the argument to list has to be a format string that denotes how to print the argument and counter. For such a format list, the first argument is the counter, and the second argument is the actual item to list. You can switch those around if you need to using the [asterisk directive](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cga.htm). The second item should be a string to print as the delimiter between each item. Finally, the rest of the list has to be the actual items to print.

```
(format T "~/iterate-counting/" '("~a:~a" " " x y z))
  => 1:X 2:Y 3:Z
(format T "~/iterate-counting/" '("~a:~/iterate-counting/" " " ("~a>~a" "," 0 1 2) ("~a>~a" "," a b c) ("~a>~a" "," x y z)))
  => 1:1>0,2>1,3>2 2:1>A,2>B,3>C 3:1>X,2>Y,3>Z
```

If you want it to start counting from zero, add an `@` modifier to the `iterate-counting`:

```
(format T "~@/iterate-counting/" '("~a:~a" " " x y z))
  => 0:X 1:Y 2:Z
```

I wouldn't personally use this, as it's far less than obvious what is going on if you stumble across the directive uninitiated. It would probably be much less confusing for the potential future reader to write a tailored function for this, than trying to ab/use `format`.

Comment: I went for your loop construct. It is easier to write and read than the `~/` directive.

Answer (score 2):

A not so simple but reusable way of producing a numbered list is by using the `~/` directive ([Tilde Slash: Call Function](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_ced.htm)) with a user-defined function. For instance:

```
(let ((position 0))
  (defun init-pos(str arg col at)
    (declare (ignore str arg col at))
    (setf position 0))
  (defun with-pos(str arg col at)
    (declare (ignore col at))
    (format str "~a:~a" (incf position) arg)))
```

and then write format like this one:

```
(format nil "~/init-pos/~{~/with-pos/~^ ~}" nil '(a b c))
```

Note that, as said in a comment, this solution has two limitations:

1. You cannot use it if you need to format objects in concurrent threads, and
2. you cannot use it for nested lists.

Comment: That's not thread safe. It also does not work for hierarchical printing - lists of lists.